# Побитовая коньюкция

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, логика

//x&51 = 0 ∨ (x&41 = 0 → x&А = 0)

```
for(unsigned int A = 1;A<= 32;A++)
{
    unsigned flag = 1;
    for(unsigned int x = 1;x<=32;x++)
    {
        if(!(((x&51)!= 0) + (((x&41)==0)) || ((x&A)== 0)))
        flag = 0;


    }
    if(flag)
    {
        cout<<A<<endl;break;
    }
}
```

Ответ:41,у меня выводит 1

Comment: не знаю,почему выводит 1,выражение в комментарии над кодом

Comment: Ну вы А ограничиваете сверху 32-мя (почему?), какие уж тут 41... А что дано? x,A? Найти все сочетания x и А или как? Вы уж дайте *точное* задание...

Comment: все равно ничего не меняется

Comment: поставил 64,тот же ответ

Comment: проблема видимо в логике

Comment: В логике изъяны еще те, но я не понимаю, что именно задано и что надо найти...

Comment: Обозначим через m&n поразрядную конъюнкцию неотрицательных целых чисел m и n.

Так, например, 14&5 = 11102&01012 = 01002 = 4.

Для какого наибольшего целого числа А формула

 

x&51 = 0 ∨ (x&41 = 0 → x&А = 0)

 

тождественно истинна (т. е. принимает значение 1 при любом неотрицательном целом значении переменной x)?

Comment: в чем проблема?

Comment: что исправить в коде

Comment: Ага, по крайтей мере условие понятно...

Answer (score 1):

Надо найти A ∨ (B → C). Но: (B → C) <=> (!B ∨ С)
Так что получаем A ∨ (!B ∨ C).

Если решать просто перебором, то получается

```
for(unsigned int A = 0; A <= 0xFF; ++A)
{
    int ok = true;
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x <= 0xFF; ++x)
        if (!(((x&51)==0) || ((x&41) != 0) || ((x&A) == 0)))
        { ok = false; break; }
    if (ok) cout << A << endl;
}
```

Выводятся

```
0
1
8
9
32
33
40
41
```

Наибольшее — 41.

Если развернуть цикл, сразу выводим наибольшее значение:

```
for(unsigned int A = 0xFF; A < 0xFFFF; --A)
{
    int ok = true;
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x <= 0xFF; ++x)
        if (!(((x&51)==0) || ((x&41) != 0) || ((x&A) == 0)))
        { ok = false; break; }
    if (ok) { cout << A << endl; break; }
}
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Но меня терзают смутные сомнения, что надо что-то более умное, чем простой перебор...

Comment: а почему там в шестнадцатиричная система счисления,и диапозон чисел такой большой?

Comment: Большой? Один байт — большой?... В принципе, можно обойтись 6 битами, раз числа небольшие (51), но для гарантии...